# Instantiate template using enum

Tags: c++, templates, enums, constants

Why does the following compilation fail with `error: ‘arg’ cannot appear in a constant-expression`?

```
class Foo {
public:
    enum myenum { BIRDY, NUMNUM };
    typedef enum myenum myenum_t;
    void bar(const myenum_t arg);
}
template<Foo::myenum_t> class MyClass {};
void Foo::bar(const myenum_t arg) {
    MyClass<arg> hey;
}
```

Are enumerated types not compile-time constants?

Comment: `arg` is a runtime-value. Templates parameters are required to be *compile-time* constructs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use variable, not just constant, there is no variables on compile-time, use template function.

```
template<myenum_t>
void bar();

template<Foo::myenum_t arg>
void Foo::bar()
{
   MyClass<arg> hey;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Enum values are compile-time constants, but you are passing a variable of enum type, the value of which isn't determined until the program is executed.